# onPause() and onResume() issues with Androids V2 maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, onresume, onpause

I have been making a running android application that uses a GoogleMap. The application uses a chronometer:

```
 <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/Duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="0:00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

This starts as soon as the Application starts. I am also maintaining an array of LatLngs that represent the users movement

```
ArrayList<LatLng> routeToPlot
```

When the application goes into the background for a short amount of time and I restore the application, it carries on as if it was in the foreground. However, if it goes in the background for a longer amount of time it is as if  the activity was never even started. I assume I need to implement some logic in these methods:

```
  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
```

However, I can't find any sort of guides as to how I should be storing and restoring the data.

I'd really appreciate some pointers or some guides on working with onPause and onResume for map activities.

thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: How does this help sorry?

Comment: Why is map data different from any other data?

Comment: It doesn't mention on there on how to implement onPause() or onResume() at all.

Comment: As long as you're able to retrieve your data from the map and load it back in, you would just need to retrieve the data and save it into a persistent data store onPause and retrieve it from your persistent data store and load it back into the map onResume.